# Rails loading image while procees remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm has image on my page, who doesn't showed

```
<img id="loading" src="<%= image_url "loading.gif" %>", style="display:none;" />
```

And form, who remote create user:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: user_index_path, remote: true do |f| %>
```

The question: is there some way to show this image while server processes my request?

As example, in .net MVC it's looks like:

Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{LoadingElementId = "imageLoading;})

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is it possible. You should use HTML File API ([here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is several examples) or third-party JS libraries used this API. Rails doesn't have appropriate functionality out of the box.